# how to add spaces between icons and the following information about it on the bumblebee-status bar (i3wm)

Tags: fonts, statusbar, i3

I started to rice my arch linux but I have a little problem with my bar.
I have a superposition with the icons and the info after I changed the font to JetBrains Nerd font semibold. I use the following bar :

```
    status_command /usr/bin/bumblebee-status \
    -m arch-update kernel cpu memory nic battery \
    spotify pasink pasource time date\
    -p time.format="%H:%M:%S" \
    -t dracula-powerline
position top
```

And the font : font pango:JetBrainsMonoNL NFM SemiBold:style=SemiBold,Regular 10

[My current desktop ->](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VByEd.jpg)

I tried to reduce the font size but anything has changed since. Maybe there is a conf file but I didn't find it.